# Android: lib module using resources from app module

Tags: android, android-resources

I have one project with two modules: the app and the lib.
Obviously the app module depends of the lib module.
However I need that the lib module uses resources (image drawables) from app module. Is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, because all library modules are compiled first, and they do not have any access to the application resources at this point. A library module must include all of the resources it is dependent on by definition. Only when the application is compiled do its resources get built into the relevant `R` classes, at which point the library is already fully compiled.

Answer (score 0):

No. The problem is that resource id-s are assigned dynamically, so you can't refer to a resource from a library, since its id is unpredictable.